# Magento Backup Tool killed the database

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, database, backup

If I click on `System > Tools > Backups` create a database backup and restore it the shop breaks. Looks like the backup is canceled in the middle.

Could this be a PHP timeout problem or is this done by a cronjob?
Is this know not to work probably?

## Update

Looks like this is a MySQL problem. Any idea what config value might cause this?

MySQL config

```
connect_timeout=120
delayed_insert_timeout=3000
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=600
interactive_timeout=28800
net_read_timeout=600
net_write_timeout=600
slave_net_timeout=3600
table_lock_wait_timeout=600
wait_timeout=18000
```

From what I can see in [backup source code](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Backup/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysql4.php) a lot of queries are running to create the dumpfile instead of a simple `mysqldump`...

## Update 2

I increased wat_timeout with success by adding into `app/code/core/Mage/Backup/Model/Resource/Db.php`

```
$this->_write->query('SET session wait_timeout = 115200;');
```

But I noticed I get a 500 Internal Server Error

```
/index.php/admin/system_backup/create/key/a74b4...7978/?isAjax=true
```

with post data: `type=db&maintenance_mode=0&backup_name=test&exclude_media=0&form_key=uPK54mu...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely a timeout of some type was encountered, be it either a MySQL or PHP timeout.

You are correct with the assuming the [backup is triggered via cron](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Backup/etc/config.xml#L68):

I would double check MySQL's timeout and logs as [PHP's timeout is set to `0`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/053e0b286cbd6d52ac69ca9fd53a3b72c78aca1d/app/code/core/Mage/Backup/Model/Db.php#L91) to avoid such issues when the cron job is executed:

The best and safest route is doing [manual backups via CLI](https://gist.github.com/molotovbliss/8866859), with `mysqldump`, and recommended over the backup tool within the admin.

**n98-magerun** has some nifty backup utilities as well via CLI worth checing out:

- https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun

Also for those running Enterprise 1.13, the backup tool does **NOT** include `TRIGGERS` (MySQL dump will however).

- https://github.com/molotovbliss/Envalo_Backup
- https://gist.github.com/molotovbliss/c176f2140232a0ba556f

Comment: That helped a lot any idea what mysql config value could be the problem?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout

Answer (score 3):

I finally managed to find the correct php error log on this stupid server:

```
mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 61 seconds
```

Solution is to increase [FcgidIOTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488567/premature-end-of-script-headers-index-php-mod-fcgid-read-data-timeout-in-61-s) and FcgidBusyTimeout massively. As this process runs very slow (multiple hours in this case) and the store is not loading during this time this is not a good option for me. If you have a small store it might be OK for you but I go with B00MERs answer and trigger a `mysqldump` from my own script.

Comment: Glad to hear, Feel free to mark your answer as correct.